# What would be a good translation of "becario"?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales

Let me explain myself, the official definition is "scholarship holder", but in some places it is a position in a company, sometimes is a *pro bono* position but most of the times is an entry level job.

Comment: Eso suena como lo que en inglés decimos "intern," lo cual es una posición en una compañía, normalmente sin sueldo, ocupado por una persona en entrenamiento en su campo.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "pro bono". Usually this refers to professional services, like legal counsel, offered without a fee, for the public good. Is the usage you gave for "becario" associated with subsidized employment?

Comment: @WalterMitty no, I meant "offered without a fee",  some countries have this form of employment that is  mandatory. But I think that the word is used sometimes as trainee and others as intern and some others as a pro bono position, that's why I was confused in the first place.

Comment: the correct word is "internship"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if "trainee" could be considered the same thing but it looks like a good candidate.

Comment: It sounds like maybe "intern" would be a possible translation. But I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Flimzy: I could be wrong but, the way I understand it is that intern is a temporary worker, like a student who is getting some experience by working at a company during the summer for example. Trainee is someone who has already been hired by the company as a permanent employee but still does not have the skills to be given the full responsibilities yet.

Answer (score 2):

Trainees and Interns can still get paid, even if its a stipend. However, a "Volunteer" does not get paid, although reimbursement for expenses, meals, lodging, transportation, clothing, supplies and other fringe benefits can be provided. If your intent is to use a "Scholarship Holder" (also knows as a "Grantee", "Recipient" or "Beneficiary") who has been assigned a school project to gain experience (also known as an "Internship") at a business, hospital, legal practice, etc.,  then the word "Intern" applies.

Answer (score 1):

The word "Fellow" is also associated with this word.